# How do I make certain words in a scrollpane colored?

Tags: java, jscrollpane

So, I'm wondering how I would go about colouring certain words in my scrollpane. After doing some research I have found almost nothing helpful. What is there to help with colouring certain words?

```
 JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    txtInfo = new JTextArea("Bot In Progress...\n");
    txtInfo.setColumns(35);
    txtInfo.setEnabled(false);
    txtInfo.setDisabledTextColor(Color.black);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(txtInfo);
```

So, here is my scrollpane. What I have it doing now is accepting outputs from part of my program and displaying them. Certain words that I want coloured are Win!(Green) and Loose(Red), and maybe some more later.

The reason why a scrollpane works the best for me is because I need the log to update constantly and the user is supposed to be able to look back up at the log at any time. Is there a better way of storing that information or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with JTextArea instead you can do it using JTextPane. You can then add the JTextPane to your JScrollPane. Have a look at this site http://javatechniques.com/blog/setting-jtextpane-font-and-color/ where it explains how to do this.

Comment: So, it will still contain the scroll functions and whatnot?

Comment: I think it should contain everything. The JTextPane is just like a pane, you can add text to it and then add it to a scroll pane. Then using the scroll pane you can add scroll functions and other things.